# React rewriting class with hooks causes re-render loops

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on an image transition react component, where it waits to have img1 loaded and then on a user click loads the img2, but fades img1 smoothly.

Tried re-writing the application with hooks to set the states - but when this is applied it creates an re-render loop error.

Is it because we are always setting img1 as currentImgSrc initially?

```
const [imgSrcOne, setImgSrcOne] = useState(currentImgSrc)
```

errors in the if/else block? or is setting the useState in the return causing the bug

tried removing the if/else block to make the application functional

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/b531L6ho/

```
import {
  ImageTransition
} from './imageTransition/imageTranition'


const {
  useState
} = React

interface ImageContainerProps {
  layer: string
  currentImgSrc: string
  notifyOnError: (url: string) => void
  updateLayerLoading: (hasLoaded: boolean) = void
}

export const ImageTransitionContainer: React.SFC < ImageContainerProps > = ({
  currentImgSrc,
  layer,
  notifyOnError,
  updateLayerLoading
}) => {


  const [imgSrcOne, setImgSrcOne] = useState(currentImgSrc)
  const [displayImgOne, setdisplayImgOne] = useState(true)
  const [imgOneLoaded, setImgOneLoaded] = useState(false)

  const [imgSrcTwo, setImgSrcTwo] = useState(currentImgSrc)
  const [displayImgTwo, setdisplayImgTwo] = useState(true)
  const [imgTwoLoaded, setImgTwoLoaded] = useState(false)


  if (imgSrcOne && currentImgSrc !== imgSrcOne) {
    console.log("in the if statement")
    setImgSrcTwo(currentImgSrc)
    setDisplayImgTwo(two)
  }

  if (currentImgSrc !== imgSrcOne) {
    setImgSrcne(currentImgSrc)
  }


  if (!imgSrcOne && !imgSrcTwo) {
    setImgSrcOne(currentImgSrc)
    setDisplayImgOne(true)
  } else if (imgSrcOne && currentImgSrc !== imgSrcOne) {
    setImgSrcTwo(currentImgSrc)
    setDisplayImgTwo(true)
  } else if (imgSrcTwo && currentImgSrc !== imgSrcTwo) {
    setImgSrcOne(currentImgSrc)
    setDisplayImgOne(true)
  }

  console.log("state --", imgSrcOne, displayImgOne, imgOneLoaded, imgSrcTwo, displayImgTwo, imgTwoLoaded)


  return ( 
    <>

      <ImageTransition
        displayImg={displayImgOne}
        imgLoaded={imgOneLoaded}
        imgSrc={imgSrcOne}
        onExit={() => {
          setImgSrcOne(null)
          setImgOneLoaded(false)
        }}
        onLoad={() => {
          setImgOneLoaded(true)
          setDisplayImgTwo(false)
        }}
      />

      <ImageTransition
        displayImg={displayImgTwo}
        imgLoaded={imgTwoLoaded}
        imgSrc={imgSrcTwo}
        onExit={() => {
          setImgSrcTwo(null)
          setImgTwoLoaded(false)
        }}
        onLoad={() => {
          setImgTwoLoaded(true)
          setDisplayImgOne(false)
        }}
      />

    </>
  )


}
```

Comment: Please, post all relevant code in the question. Screenshots aren't acceptable, unless they show something that plain text couldn't.

Comment: I will have to rewrite it - I only have a bulk of the code as a screenshot --- is this a common issue with hooks?

Comment: Yes, the issue is common. set* shouldn't be called in the body of a component.

Comment: when you say body of the component - which part - inside the return?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b531L6ho/  I have re-written it here

Comment: I see - so you think its the issue with the onLoad/onExit -- this code works as normal without the hooks --- but when we looked to replace the hooks it borks

Comment: The render parts come from callbacks inside the custom component itself (the child component)

Comment: Thanks. I cannot say about onExit because you didn't show what ImageTransition is but it's possible that it contributes to the problem. What I mean is `if (imgSrcOne && currentImgSrc !== imgSrcOne)` etc should be moved to `useEffect` to avoid infinite loops, possibly with the help of  `[...]` inputs argument.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the useEffect parts -- its a kind of garbage collector in the child component --- if image has loaded -- if the image has been exited/deleted cleared - its an image transitioner cssTransition I think

Comment: ah you mean wrap it in a useEffect function just under the set states

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/b531L6ho/1/

Comment: Yes, something like this. useEffect is a good starter. Providing a way to replicate the problem will help to quickly debug it. These conditions are likely unexpectedly false at some point and cause infinite state updates.

Comment: I had noticed that the default state for imgSrcOne is always set as currentImg - and on one of the load/exit parts an attempt is made to null this - but I was wondering if it is always set as currentImg - during these loops?

Comment: If this is not expected then this is one of the problems with conditions. It doesn't have a chance to be set to anything but currentImgSrc because of `if (currentImgSrc !== imgSrcOne) { setImgSrcne(currentImgSrc)`.

Comment: I think the original code contained just the if and else if block - and else was return null as in no state change --- if (!imgSrcOne && !imgSrcTwo) {
    setImgSrcOne(currentImgSrc)
    setDisplayImgOne(true)
  } else if (imgSrcOne && currentImgSrc !== imgSrcOne) {
    setImgSrcTwo(currentImgSrc)
    setDisplayImgTwo(true)
  }

Comment: This looks promising - https://codesandbox.io/s/5vrl6qj7jx

Comment: Yes, that's how I would expect this to be done.

Comment: Where are the image sources coming from? What sets them?

Comment: I think an external server